# Django Flutter Ecommerce Shopping Cart

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, e-commerce

I am attempting to build an ecommerce site with a functional shopping cart that does not require a user to login before adding/removing items. To add this functionality I plan to store information based around the user's device to remember their order history, current items in cart, etc. For this, I am using a python Django backend (Django Rest Framework) and a Dart Flutter front end.

This is going to be solely a web application to start and then cross into a mobile application, hence why I am using flutter.

My question is more of a general architecture question rather than specific coding. I have done a lot of research as to how to grab a device ID using the flutter front end and then send that device ID to the backend Django application through a cookie. My question is if this is the right direction to go?

Do I use flutter to create the cookie and then send it via POST request to the backend to manage the shopping cart? Or do I create the device ID through django backend some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion - to use "device ID" is a bad way to keep the cart information.

Why:

- it is not work without additional code if many users use the same device.
- it is not work, if i want to be an "anonym customer".
- it is not work, if i don't allow to get 'device id'.
- it can be hacked, if i use 'device id' from other customer.

Django gives you a good (not the best) possibility - to work with sessions.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/

Probably you can use this possibility?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have worked with Django Sessions over the past day or so (since your reply) and this is what I need. Does the session need to be set up in Flutter? Because when I launch the flutter web application (http://localhost:51496), I don't see a session key created like I do when I look at the Django Rest Framework displayed in my django backend (http://127.0.0.1:8000).

Comment: Check your settings  - it can be in cookies or in headers. We use Vue / axious - in  every answer I have session id

Comment: accepting this answer, as it guided me in the right direction. I actually ended up ditching django and using back4app as a backend service.